# Adding text to multiple JTextAreas in different tabs of a JTabbedPane dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic, jtable, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

So I am dynamically adding `JTextArea`s to a `JTabbedPane` on the click of a `JTable` cell. I was wondering how to also set the text of the `JTextArea` dynamically. I was looking at trying to use `getSelectedIndex()` nested in `getComponentAt()`, but this returns a `Component` rather than a `JTextArea` so I will not be able to `setText()` this way. I'm wondering if instead I need to build an `Array` or `ArrayList` of `new JTextArea`s and add to the `Array` or `ArrayList` each time a cell is selected and then from the `getSelectedIndex()` and set the corresponding `JTextArea`s text. The necessary code is below:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            viewerPane.addTab((String) table.getValueAt(row, 0), null , new JPanel().add(new JTextArea()), (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0));
            viewerPane.setSelectedIndex(viewerPane.getComponentCount()-1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map` keyed with the tab index and valued with the `JTextArea` at that index:

```
Map<Integer, JTextArea> indexToTextArea = new HashMap<>();//Instance variable
....
//in the MouseListener:
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
viewerPane.addTab((String) table.getValueAt(row, 0), null , new JPanel().add(textArea), (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0));
viewerPane.setSelectedIndex(viewerPane.getComponentCount()-1);
indexToTextArea.put(viewerPane.getComponentCount()-1, textArea);
```

When you want to get the `JTextArea` of the currently selected tab index for instance, just look up in the `Map`

```
JTextArea selectedTextArea =  indexToTextArea.get(viewer.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you, but I have now run into another issue. I was not able to see all my text that was being displayed because it was too large. I attempted changing `new JPanel().add(textArea)` to `new JScrollPane().add(textArea)` but this still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you see the `JScrollPanel`? Perhaps the `LayoutManager` of the tab is not sizing the `Component` properly - one thing to try is to add the `JScrollPane` to a `JPanel`, and add that `JPanel` to the `JTabbedPane`

Comment: I do not even see the `JScrollPane` and I have already tried adding it to the `JPanel` as well.

Comment: Add the `JTextArea` to the Viewport of the `JScrollPane` - do so by either passing the `JTextArea` to it's constructor, or calling `setViewportView`

Answer (score 2):

You are adding:

```
 new JPanel().add(new JTextArea())
```

as new Tab.

That means, `getComponentAt()` will return **exactly** this `JPanel` you added.
This `JPanel` is type of `Component` and contains your `JTextArea.`

What you could do (since this `JPanel` does **only** contain a `JTextArea`):

```
//verbose code:
Component cmp = tab.getComponentAt(0 /*index of tab*/);
JPanel pnl = (JPanel)cmp; //cast to JPanel
Component cmp2 = pnl.getComponent(0);  //get first child component
JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)cmp2; //cast to JTextArea
```

as Helper-Method:

```
public JTextArea getTextAreaFromTab(JTabbedPane p_tabbedPane, int p_tabIdx)
{
   Component cmp = p_tabbedPane.getComponentAt(p_tabIdx /*index of tab*/);
   JPanel pnl = (JPanel)cmp; //cast to JPanel
   Component cmp2 = pnl.getComponent(0);  //get first child component
   JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)cmp2; //cast to JTextArea
   return textArea;
}
```